# switchMap in Pipetransformation only returns last char of string

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am writing a Pipe that is supposed to retrieve an observable from a service that emits a translation object which is basically just a javascript object. The pipe takes in the key of the object to get the right translation and returns an observable that should emit exactly that translation.

But somehow it only returns the last char of the translation string, eventhough I use switchMap.

Pipe Usage:

```
{{ 'abc' | translotus:'shared' | async }}
```

Pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'translotus'
})
export class TranslotusPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private translotus: TranslotusService) { }

  transform(value: string, ...args: string[]): Observable<string> {
    if (!value) return EMPTY;
    if (!args) return EMPTY;
    if (args.length < 1) return EMPTY;

    return this.translotus.getTranslations(args[0]).pipe(
      switchMap(translations => {
        /*
         translations = {
          abc: 'Test Translation'
         }
        */
        if (!translations) return EMPTY;
        return translations[value] as string ?? EMPTY;
      })
    ); // --> but output is just 'n' ???
  }
}
```

Comment: It look like you just need a map there, not a switchMap?

Comment: Man you a right. I feel so stupid now. Thanks!

Comment: No worries - happens to all of us . Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

getTranslations does not return a higher order observable, hence a usual map does the job.

Thanks to Mike One, who pointed it out!